# Adding a varibale to the RouteDefination "from " in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

I am looking to amend the RouteDefination from in Apache Camel

I hav eproperties file as below
     test1=test
     queue1=queue

code as below

```
from( "activemq:queue:{{test1}}.{{queue1}}")
.transform()
.simple(" ${body} {{test1}}.{{queue1}}.hello ${date:now:yyyyMMdd}")
.to("stream:out");
```

this will become for route as

```
from( "activemq:queue:test1.queue")
```

i am looking to make it as

```
from( "activemq:queue:test1.queue_20170606")
```

which is ${date:now:yyyyMMdd}

Comment: It is not clear what is a purpose to do that? Do you try to create new queue every day? for what? Maybe it is good to revise your system design?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Camel - the `from` endpoint is static.

However ActiveMQ supports queue wildcards which you can use to consume from multiple queues, and you can use JMS message selectors.

- http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html
- http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html

The latter is not so performant as it needs to do a query on the queue.

If you want to do a route per yyyyMMdd, then you need to add/remove routes dynamic in Camel. See other questions on SO how to do that.